# queryBroadcastReceivers does not find receivers registered with registerReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I need to find out which broadcast receivers can handle a given Intent.

It seems that *queryBroadcastReceivers()* does not return receivers registered in code using *registerReceiver()* but only receivers declared in *AndroidManifest.xml*.

Is this behavior by design?

Any other way to find **all** installed receivers for some Intent ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like it's not possible to detect receivers registered in code, as per this recent message on the mailing list: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/msg/5fd1cdb24b2a6760

This is disappointing as I was looking for a way to do the same thing.

Comment: I have the same problem right now, and your answer is 3 years old. Now, is there a new way to list the broadcast receivers registered with `registerReceiver()` ?

Comment: @Vincent looks like it stays the same, there's no such a way.

Comment: if you think about it you will know there's no such way to do that , Android's broadcast receiver is able to receive message even without running the app, for example listen to REBOOT event from device, which means Android system will scan your app's manifest and record those receiver register in manifest when your app is installed. Putting your receiver in code will not be able to make your receiver recorded in the system's receiver table.

Answer (score 1):

If the receivers you're interested in are yours, you can use [sendOrderedBroadcast](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#sendOrderedBroadcast%28android.content.Intent,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.BroadcastReceiver,%20android.os.Handler,%20int,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle%29) instead of regular broadcast.

This makes the broadcast goes to all registered receivers one by one, according to priority, and finally to your supplied broadcast receiver, which according to the result/data passed to it, can figure out which receivers handled this before it.

You can check this example project which uses this method:
http://www.mannaz.at/codebase/android-activity-foreground-surveillance/